# Getting Bootstrap tabs to fill height automatically down to footer?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, header, height, sticky-footer

I'm having the following issue:

I have a bootstrap based header row, tabbed content row with 3 columns, and footer row. I would like the tabbed content row to make use of the max available screen space up to the footer. This should always result in an even line of the bottom of 3 tabbed areas.

I've tried several things referenced here in the past, but wasn't able to make any of them work for me correctly.

I've set up a jsfiddle with an example of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/VDtgT/embedded/result/

Here's my sloppy example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/1.1.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>

hr {
border: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #f00;
background-color: #000;
height: 1px;
margin-top: 2px; 
margin-bottom: 3px; 
 }

img { 
border:1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

body { margin: 2px 2px 0px 2px }



</style>  <!-- // Main CSS styles -->   

</head> 
    <body>


<!-- *** TOP ROW -->
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
<div class="span12" style="background-color: #ddd;" align="center">HEADER</div>
    </div> 
<hr>

<!-- *** MIDDLE ROW --->
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">

      <div class="tabbable" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab11" data-toggle="tab">Group1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab12" data-toggle="tab">Group2</a></li>
          </ul>


          <div class="tab-content" style="padding-bottom: 9px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab11">                        
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <button style="width: 48%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">BUTTON</button>



            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab12">
            <Pre>Empty</pre>
            </div>



        </div>
          </div>
        </div> 




            <div class="span3">
       <div class="tabbable" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab Two</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content" style="padding-bottom: 9px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />

    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />

    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>  
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
    <button style="width: 45%" type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success">button</button>
<br />
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <pre>Empty</pre>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div> 

        </div>




                    <div class="span5">


 <div class="tabbable" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">                        

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab98" data-toggle="tab">Pane1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab99" data-toggle="tab">Pane2</a></li>
          </ul>


          <div class="tab-content" style="padding-bottom: 9px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">         

          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab98">  

              <br />
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a>             </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<br />

<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a>    </div>
<br />

<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>
<div class="span3"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img1"></a> </div>


</div>


   <div class="tab-pane" id="tab99">            
<pre>Empty</pre>
            </div>

        </div>



</div>
</div>  






        </div>

<hr>        
<!-- FOOTER BEGIN --> 


<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12" style="background-color: #ddd;" align="center">
    Goal: Footer stuck to bottom of screen & bottom of the 3 tab frames directly above (regardless of content). Button blocks should expand with vertical spacing as needed to fill screen to footer.
</div>
</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I was able to get pretty close to what I want...

I used the Bootstrap "sticky footer navbar" example here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html for sticking the footer to the bottom.  But the "magic" of the automatically sizing the tabs happens via jquery dynamically setting max-height and min-height CSS variables. I just adjusted the multiplier until the bottom of the tabs were high enough off of the footer for my liking.

The updated fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/VDtgT/9/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get pretty close..

I used the Bootstrap "sticky footer navbar" example here: twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html

This is for sticking the footer to the bottom.

The "magic" of the automatically sizing the tabs happens via jquery dynamically setting max-height and min-height CSS variables. I just adjusted the multiplier until the bottom of the tabs were high enough off of the footer for my liking. fwiw, I also just found the jquery "equalize" command which may be a cleaner way of doing the same: (http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/)

Anyway, the final updated fiddle for my example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VDtgT/19/embedded/result

```
<b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to fix the size of the tabs? You can have them being variable and that will push the footer down when the content requires it.

Looking at you latest code, you don't seem to use the `#wrap` or the `.push` that the example you mention is using. You will need to wrap your content, and then add a `<div class="push"></div>` just like in the example.

Comment: Yes, sticky footer was part of the solution (mentioned in my comment above). The other part, I think, required jquery to dynamically set max-height and min-height for the tabbed content areas. Now I am just trying to figure out how to center the buttons with even spacing between each button row... hopefully that will be an easier problem :)

Comment: I always seem to be a minute behind your latest post! I updated my reply. As I say I can't see you wraping the content or using the push <div>. If you are happy with what you have now, for the centering you are looking at <div> vertical align.

Comment: Ack. Sorry, you're right. I guess I was working in my pre-forked version of the jfiddle.  Just so the right code is here for reference, here it is:   http://jsfiddle.net/VDtgT/19/embedded/result/

Comment: Sorry didn't see your question. I'm fixing the tabs because this is for an app gui. Target is a tablet, but we'll occasionally use on a large touch monitor as well. I want the look and feel of the GUI to be the same regardless of the target device.  (Sorry... I'm about 7 years behind on webdev terminology, catching up) :)